Credit Card failure when Pay Later enabled
We have form with both Pay Later and Credit Card options enabled.  When the user selects and pays with Credit Card, the payment is sent to Stripe, but status is Uncaptured.  The Pay Later instructions also show up.  When Pay Later is disabled, credit card (Stripe) works correctly.  Civi just updated to latest, as well as Stripe extension.  Any ideas on why this would be?

Is this a CiviCRM contribution page or a drupal 10 webform? If the latter, try adding this patch to webform civicrm module - https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/937

In my case this is a CiviCRM contribution page on a Wordpress site. I can confirm that disabling Pay Later lets the Stripe transaction proceed correctly. Don't know if it's a bug in CiviCRM Core or the Stripe extension, but either way it's a PITA. https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/476

This is CiviCRM contribution page on Joomla site for me.

I can confirm that we've been seeing this issue for some time now, where the Stripe form is moved to the Confirmation page of Events AND used in conjunction with a "Pay later" option.  It seems that so long as a "Pay later" option is available to an event (even if it's not used), Stripe decides that it should not be processing any payment for the event on Confirmation.  Which is a particularly nasty issue, as the Customer sees the confirmation screen and is likely to think that they have booked and paid - but they've only registered for the event.
We have raised the issue with MJW Consulting who works on the CiviCRM Stripe Extension.

MJW working with MJW - good to see
